# Can I use a hardcoded path for a database?

Tags: android, database, filepath

I have written the following line in order to find the path of a database in order to open it:

```
private static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.FMF/databases/";
```

It currently comes up with a warning saying:

```
Do not hardcode "/data/"; use Context.getFilesDir().getPath() instead
```

My question is can the hardcoded version work on actual devices? and if not how do i implement the other method?

Comment: It might work on most devices at present, but there's not guarantee that it will continue to.  Why can't you try the suggested alternative from your post?

Comment: You should never use hardcoded approach in also another issues like non-parametrized statements, paths to databases, files and files on sd card. It may work on some devices but not in all. It also depends on version of API used by device.

Comment: why would you even use a path ? you usually don't even need it.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is can the hardcoded version work on actual devices?

Many, but not all. It certainly will not work on Android 4.2+ tablets where the app is being run by somebody with a secondary account or restricted profile.

> and if not how do i implement the other method?

Step #1: Delete `DB_PATH` from your source code

Step #2: Everywhere that you now have compile errors because you no longer define `DB_PATH`, modify your code to build a path to a database file [via `getDatabasePath()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29), a method available on any `Context`, such as an `Activity`.

Comment: do i just write there getDatabasePath() then?

Comment: @user2957710: `getDatabasePath()` takes a `String` parameter that is the name of your database file, and it returns to you the full path to where that database file should reside.

Comment: yes i get that, but what do i actually write i have the line to open the database:

Comment: rDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, 0);  where mPath is the path so what do i change mPath to?

Comment: @user2957710: You replace it with the results of your call to `getDatabasePath()`. Or, you don't use `openDatabase()` at all, but instead use `SQLiteOpenHelper`.